# Simulate Click before

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, velo

I have a website which I am trying to scrape data from https://www.shapiro-ingle.com/sales.aspx?state=NC. Unfortunately, I have to click "Search" before a table on the page will populate with the information I need. The URL also remains the same. So, when I run use a fetch to get the source code it does not include the data I need.

Is there a simple way to trigger something like document.getElementById("SubmitBtn").click(); to load the data I need before the httpResponse occurs?

```
  export function data_scrape(url) {
       return fetch(url, {method: 'get'})
      .then( (httpResponse) => {
        if (httpResponse.ok) {
          return httpResponse.text();
      } else {
        return "Error";
      }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mouse event and dispatch it to the desired element

```
var elem = document.getElementById("SubmitBtn")
var click = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window
});
elem.dispatchEvent(click);
```

---

EDIT:

Send POST to the form endpoint

```
// db can be upcoming_sales or sales_held
// county can be any of the options in the drop down
var data = "db=upcoming_sales&county=Alamance" 

fetch(url, {
    method: "POST"
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
}).then(...)
```

Comment: I understand this code as a standalone, but can you elaborate as to how I would actually integrate that into my fetch code?

Comment: Ah I see. Your original question was unclear. I thought you were trying to simulate a click event using a headless browser. If all you want is to grab the data that populates the table, send a POST to /sales.aspx?state=NC with these form-encoded fields: db, county. I figured this out by using 'Inspect Element' on Chrome that the form sends those fields to that endpoint on submit.

Comment: Awesome, makes sense. Thanks for additional detail and code!